# Installing HANA Express on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, hana

My laptop is running Ubuntu 8G RAM, I'd like to know if it's possible to install SAP HANA Express or ASE suit on it, localhost, without using virtual machines or a remote server.

All tutorials I've seen require either a VM or a server, I'd just like to install HANA Express locally to learn how to use it.

Is there a simple way to install and run HANA Express on ubuntu?

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Requests for pre-install advice, tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The server install that you mentioned is simply a linux system where you can install the binaries. So it actually does not matter if the system is a "server" or your laptop.

The "Server Only" version of SAP HANA express is the core database layer and provides all the text analytics, geo spatial, predictive, etc and will run as a VM on 8GB of memory. If you take the same binaries that are provided and are used to create the VM to begin with you will find that it only takes somewhere between 2GB and 4GB of memory to start with.

But with only 8GB of available memory on your system that means that you will quickly hit limitations based on what else is running on your system and of course how much you try to do with the SAP HANA express system.

Last night I actually did the Docker install version and have HXE running on my 8GB laptop without a problem. I did give Docker 6GB of the system memory and my HXE system has 1GB of available free memory upon startup.

[image]

Now this was Docker on a Mac. If you take the binaries and follow the install instructions on your 8GB Ubuntu laptop you should see better performance.

So long worded answer in short terms means "YES you can install SAP HANA express on your 8GB laptop"

Now interpreting your question "if it's possible to install SAP express hana or ASE suit[e]" the above answers "SAP express hana" for "ASE suit[e]" the assumption is you mean "the ABAP stack running on ASE or HANA" in which case the answer is also yes but again with limitations coming sooner than later.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)